# Using textlables in android AchartEngine when desigen charts

Tags: java, android, charts, achartengine, linechart

I'm make a line chart using achartengin, I use this cord for get x and y values.so the broth x and y axis contain integer values

```
public GraphicalView getView(Context context)
{

    (......)
    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1");
        for( int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            series.add(x[i], y[i]);
        }

    //allows more than 1 line to be added to linegraph  
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    //customize lines
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();



    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);



   return  ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer);



       }
```

[image]

but i want to add string values for x axis without using integer value but the problem is

```
TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1");
        for( int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            series.add(x[i], y[i]);
        }
```

the problem is`

```
series.add(x[i], y[i]);
```

must have two integer values

so for my requirement i use this cord to set string values for x axis

```
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(0, "Isuru");
(...)
```

then i get the x axis by overriding the pass integer values. and not it display very ugly like this[image]

so how to over come this problem   please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
renderer.setXLabels(0);
```

Comment: according my cord it must be XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); mRenderer.setXLabels(0);

Comment: Thank your very much for your help. that's the answer for my problem, i spend hole day to  solve this  problem, thank your very much.you save my time .

Answer (score 2):

You should setup following objects:

```
        //renderer is XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);//xMin = 0
        renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);//xMax = 4 or 5
```

this will make scale lower. Chart will show only 4 values instead of 6.
Also you can decrease text size of x labels

```
renderer.setLabelsTextSize(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.label_text_size));
```

Comment: Thank you. from above code it set the text labels size isn't , but my problem is some integer values are display on the label text . I want to slow the string values on the x axis, and remove the numbers from the x axis.If u know the solution for that problem please help me